# svn2git migration: analysing structure of code-tree

Tags: git, svn, migration, branch, analysis

I'm trying to convert an SVN-repository to `git`.
The repository consists of a bout 17000 commits, so I'm using KDE's `svn2git` (aka `svn-all-fast-export`).

My problem is that the repository has been restructured a few times (first it was converted from CVS; `vendor`-branches have been renamed,...)

It took a while until the project switched to a `/trunk`, `/branches` & `/tag` layout, but then the project has a large number of submodules, and they are organized e.g.

```
/trunk/plugins/foo
/trunk/plugins/bar
/branches/plugins/foo/1.0
/branches/plugins/foo/1.1
/branches/plugins/bar/1.0
/tags/plugins/pizzapack/3.14/foo
/tags/plugins/pizzapack/3.14/foo
```

Of coruse all those submodules contain subdirectory trees as well.

The directory structure in */tags* and */branches* might have changed over time, and is certainly not very consistent.

Now the good news is, that `svn2git` allows me to handle all this.

The bad news is, that I need an overview over the evolution of the directory/branching structure, before I can start instructing `svn2git`.

So I'm looking for a way to analyse the structural changes of the filesystem layout over time: *addition, removal, copying and moving of directories*.

I'm currently thinking of building a small helper-tool to allow me to do that, but I'm already stuck at properly tracking *directory-only* changes.
Not to speak about a proper representation of the changes, that would allow me to easily understand what happened.

What have you come up with, what are you using when tackling such a project?

Answer (score 1):

You can try SubGit of version [3.0.0](http://www.subgit.com/eap) or later to detect your repository structure.

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url <projectURL> --layout auto --trunk trunk repo.git
```

where `--trunk` option specifies relative path from  to the directory that play a role of trunk in the latest revision (with no leading or trailing slashes, e.g. `--trunk path/to/trunk` or `--trunk trunk`; if in the latest revision your repository has classic trunk/branches/tags structure, it should be just `--trunk trunk`).
This command will scan your repository history, track all moves, copies and renames of the trunk directory specified and generate `repo.git` directory with `subgit/config` file in it reflecting your repository structure in trunk/branches/tags/shelves options. Note that the command does not detect automatically branches that were added incorrectly with just "svn add" but not with "svn cp"/"svn mv".

You can then start translation with SubGit:

```
$ subgit install repo.git
```

Or you can try to copy-and-paste trunk/branches/tags options generated to your git-svn/svn2git config file. I'm not sure the second approach will work for 100% of cases but for more or less simple repository structures this will work as the options generated have the same format as corresponding git-svn options.

Disclaimer: I'm one of SubGit developers. SubGit is a commercial tool, but it's free for one-time conversion (import).